# WPF 4.6: the type Galasof.MVVMLight.Platform is building with an old version of blend

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that I am creating with VS2015 and I have updated my MVVM Light packge with the last one, version 5.1.1.

But in my XAML editor, I can see my controls because i get an error that says that the type Galasof.MVVMLight.Platform is building with an old version of blend and is not supported on windows presentation fundation 4 project.

So I would like to know if there is any way to solve this problem.

Thank so much.

Comment: I have the same problem when I reference System.Windows.Interactivity version 4.5, I had to downgrade to 4.0 to get my views rendered at design time.

Comment: It's an option, change to 4.0 to design an compile to 4.5, but i would be better if the problem can be solved.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on it too, if you come to a solution please post it here, I will do the same if find it first.

Comment: I will do that if I find a solution. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I still struggle with this issue but a co-worker installed a fresh System: Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2015 and problem disappear from his box. So the problem seems to arise when one previously had Visual Studio 2013 and install side by side 2015.

Comment: The problem is that the library Windows.Iteractivity used with MVVM Light is older than the new one. The new one is the version 4.5 and has problems. But I still have not solved  the problem.

Comment: I have a fresh installation of windows 10 and VS2015 community and the problem persists, so the problem it does not seem to be with previous installation of VS2013.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, but the problem even do not seems to be your MVVM Light. I created an empty project, no third party library, just a Window with a button, attached a Behavior to the button created with System.Windows.Interactivity 4.5.. The result is the same problem, this is annoying.

Comment: When I comment the line with the "cmd:" label (cmd is to use the MVVM Light) and the behaviours, then I can edit the axml. So by the moment I am comment the lines with this problem, edit my controls and later I uncomment the code. But this is not the solution. In my case I have few lines with this problem in the axml, but in big projects is not a solution.